# How to avoid this injection of script in the url of my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss

I am a new ASP.NET developer and my instructor forced me to develop a secure website/web-based application. After submitting my first application, and he told me that the application is vulnerable to cross-site scripting, and he proved me that by asking me to change the URL to the application from:

```
http://localhost/testapp/default.aspx
```

to

```
http://localhost/testapp/default.aspx?--></script><script>alert(30999)</script>
```

and I got a pop-up window that shows 30999.

**So how to prevent this kind of vulnerability?**

I searched on the web and I found that RequestValidate feature in ASP.NET should prevent this kind of attack, but why it did not work in my situation.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems like this kind of injection is only dangerous if you aren't using parameterized queries...which in this day in age, is <emph>mandatory</emph>.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is stopped by  RequestValidate feature in ASP.NET , http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/preventing-javascript-encoding-xss-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx This will help you in detail . One of the reason that I see it is not stopped is  rather than  in the starting